# Fast line drawing on iOS using Swift and Core Graphics

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I need to draw a line chart on iOS and thought that Core Graphics is the best performing candidate to do so.

For this custom chart control I've created a subclass of UIView with a method called drawChart that is being called on value change of a slider, or when the data changes, so quite frequently.

Within this method is a loop that calculates the x and y positions of each data set;

```
lines = [];
for var i:Int = startX; i < endX; ++i {    
    lines.append(LinePoint(x: xDC!, y: yDC!));
}
```

"lines" is an Array of Lines, Line being a model class that stores the line segments x and y values (CGPoint).

Eventually, the drawChart function calls self.setNeedsDisplay();

I then override drawRect which looks like the following;

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)  {

    if(lines.count == 0) {
            return
    }

    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    var firstLine:LinePoint = lines[0]
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, firstLine.x, firstLine.y);

    for var i:Int = 1; i<lines.count;++i {
        var loopLine:LinePoint = lines[i]    
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, loopLine.x, loopLine.y);
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
```

In short, this is slow as hell, especially appending lines to the Array is everything but fast.

Ideally I'd like to avoid caching the line points to the array and draw them directly, I can't get the proper context the drawChart method, however (CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0), which is why I figured that it needs to be in the drawRect method.

How can I speed this up? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why not use an existing plotting and graphing library, perhaps [CorePlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot)?

Comment: Definitely an option, thanks @duci9y. However, given that we already have our charting library in place (written in other languages) we'd like to port it to iOS and Android later, that way we can re-use all of our code and just replace the raw drawing methods specific to each platform.

Comment: Found out that you can get the context from drawRect(), store in in a local variable and then use it anywhere in the same class. Still getting some weird results, though.

Comment: @AlBirdie - That context is only going to be valid during `drawRect()`. You'll need to do your drawing within that method for things being rendered to the screen. You could set up your drawing using external methods or functions, then feed the context into those when you call them within `drawRect()`.

Comment: @BradLarson, that works exactly like it should! Thank you very much for your comment. Highly appreciate it. The only question that remains, is this really the fastest way to draw something like this? I mean is using CGContextAddLine (so CoreGraphics I suppose) the fastest method possible?

Comment: @AlBirdie - Rasterization of complex shapes will always be slow using Core Graphics, so you'll want to avoid redrawing elements that don't need to be drawn as you animate. Cache reused portions of your drawing in CALayers, and only redraw the bare minimum to update your scene. Core Plot does this as an optimization, for example. For the absolute fastest drawing speed, you can draw using OpenGL ES, but that will take a large amount of effort and code to do. Again, look to what Core Plot does for its graphs (I was one of the original contributors there).

Comment: @BradLarson, Well, I guess OpenGL ES is needs to be then. :) We've got a very extensive charting library (pretty much like the shinobi charts) for financial charts and with all those indicators and such, the rendering needs to be as fast as possible. Any hints where to look specifically at Core Plot? There's just so much code and I honestly have no idea where to look. Mind that I am a Swift beginner and have no experience with Obj C thus far, whatsoever, which doesn't make the task any simpler. ;)

Comment: Almost forgot. Brad if you could post your first comment as an answer I could mark this question as answered. It definitely solved the the original issue.